# wcf and inserting information into the web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, web-config

Why does WCF not insert basic information about my service into the web.config?  Is there a way to make it to that?

I'm talking about when you add a wcf service to project explorer

Comment: You mean when you add a service reference or when you create a new project?

Comment: Add service reference usually works. Although I almost never use it since I normally share interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [SvcConfigEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) to configure your services or clients. This has a *nicer* (but far from perfect) UI which can help you going quickly.

Comment: this is a nice interface but i just got burned because I didn't put the namespace before the service name.